# Necessary to lexicographically distribute document names when implementing document shards in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters#swift

The example of implementing a distributed counter in Firestore using document shards names all of the documents in lexicographical succession ("0", "1", "2", "3", etc.). Because the collection will never have more than 10 documents (per the example), does it matter how the documents are named? Is there any difference in terms of hotspotting if the documents are named like they are in the example or if their names are distributed among the ASCII keyspace such as between "0" and "z"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> does it matter how the documents are named?

No.

> Is there any difference in terms of hotspotting if the documents are named like they are in the example or if their names are distributed among the ASCII keyspace such as between "0" and "z"?

No.